# Changing NA values in a column to preceding values until other binary number appears

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this:

```
SN  TimeStamp      MOTOR
1   1/27/20 18:00   0
2   1/27/20 18:01   NA
3   1/27/20 18:02   1
4   1/27/20 18:03   NA
5   1/27/20 18:04   0
6   1/27/20 18:05   1
7   1/27/20 18:06   NA
8   1/27/20 18:07   NA
9   1/27/20 18:08   0
```

Basically, my question is how can I change the NA value to its presiding value?  I mean for NA in row 2, the answer would be the same as earlier row number 1 i.e. 0. For NAs at row 7 and 8, the answer would be that of row 6 which is 1. For NA at row 4, the value would be replaced by the number in row 3, which is 1.

Is it possible to program like that?

I would be thankful if anyone could help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is easily done with `zoo::na.locf`

Comment: This could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value

Comment: Also this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace NA with previous or next value, by group, using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr)

Comment: This did exact opposite. That replaced NAs with the value at the bottom. Is it possible to replace the value of NA with the value exactly above it. Thanks you so much for pointing out this article.

Comment: `zoo::na.locf(df$MOTOR)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
while(any(is.na(df$MOTOR))
{
  na_entries <- which(is.na(df$MOTOR))
  df$MOTOR[na_entries] <- df$MOTOR[na_entries - 1]
}
```

Comment: BOOM!! This is the killer!! Thank you so much bro. This solved the problem.. Now I can sleep in peace..